# Java abstract method overriding

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

I have the following class hierarchy

```
abstract class A {
  public abstract void M();
}

class B extends A {
  public void M() {
    //some stuff
  }
}
```

A obj=new B();

Now i want to write a new implementation of method M in a new class C such that a call obj.M() should execute my new implementation in class C? What should i do?
by the way i cant change A obj=new C();

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: You'll need to specify that that reference is actually a C. A instance = new C();

Comment: read about inheritence, overloading, and overriding....you will be fine....

Comment: @uzair_syed That is an absurd requirement. Can you please elaborate on why you can't take the straightforward approach of creating a class C that extends A and then create an instance of C, assigning it to a reference of A?. Is this something you are playing around with?

Comment: as most of u suggested create a class C that extends A and then create an instance of C would work...but i in my code dat was not possible...so i found out another way to do wat i wanted to do....anyways thanks all for the help

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting your question as *"how should I structure my code so that I can change the implementation of A that obj refers to from implementation B to implementation C, without changing `A obj = new B();` to `A obj = new C();` (Because I don't want to make the same change whenever I want to use a different implementation.)"*

In that case, check out the [concept of factories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)#Applicability).